# SQL delivery query performance

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I need a "little" help with an SQL query (MySQL).

I have the following tables:

`COURIERS` table:

> ```
> +------------+
> | COURIER_ID |
> +------------+
> ```

`DELIVERIES` table:

> ```
> +-------------+------------+------------+
> | DELIVERY_ID | COURIER_ID | START_DATE |
> +-------------+------------+------------+
> ```

`ORDERS` table:

> ```
> +----------+-------------+-------------+
> | ORDER_ID | DELIVERY_ID | FINISH_DATE |
> +----------+-------------+-------------+
> ```

`COORDINATES` table:

> ```
> +-------------+-----+-----+------+
> | DELIVERY_ID | LAT | LNG | DATE |
> +-------------+-----+-----+------+
> ```

In the real database I have more columns in each table, but for this example the above columns are enough.

What do I need?

- An SQL query that returns all couriers [`COURIER_ID`], their last
  delivery [`DELIVERY_ID`] (based on last `START_DATE`), the
  delivery's last coordinate [`LAT` and `LNG`] (based on last `DATE`) and the remaining orders count (total of orders of the last delivery that have no `FINISH_DATE`).
- A courier can have no deliveries, in this case I want `DELIVERY_ID` =
  NULL, `LAT` = NULL and `LNG` = NULL in the result.
- A delivery can have no coordinates, in this case I want `LAT` = NULL 
  and `LNG` = NULL in the result.

What was I able to do?

```
SELECT c.`COURIER_ID`,
       d.`DELIVERY_ID`,
       r.`LAT`,
       r.`LNG`,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ORDER_ID`)
   FROM `ORDERS`
   WHERE `DELIVERY_ID` = d.`DELIVERY_ID`
     AND `FINISH_DATE` IS NULL) AS REMAINING_ORDERS

FROM `COURIERS` AS c
LEFT JOIN `DELIVERIES` AS d USING (`COURIER_ID`)
LEFT JOIN `COORDINATES` AS r ON r.`DELIVERY_ID` = d.`DELIVERY_ID`

WHERE (CASE WHEN
         (SELECT MAX(`START_DATE`)
          FROM `DELIVERIES`
          WHERE `COURIER_ID` = c.`COURIER_ID`) IS NULL THEN d.`START_DATE` IS NULL ELSE d.`START_DATE` =
         (SELECT MAX(`START_DATE`)
          FROM `DELIVERIES`
          WHERE `COURIER_ID` = c.`COURIER_ID`) END)
  AND (CASE WHEN
         (SELECT MAX(`DATE`)
          FROM `COORDINATES`
          WHERE `DELIVERY_ID` = d.`DELIVERY_ID`) IS NULL THEN r.`DATE` IS NULL ELSE r.`DATE` =
         (SELECT MAX(`DATE`)
          FROM `COORDINATES`
          WHERE `DELIVERY_ID` = d.`DELIVERY_ID`) END)
GROUP BY c.`COURIER_ID`
ORDER BY d.`START_DATE` DESC
```

The problem is that this query is very slow (from 5 to 20 seconds) when I have over 5k `COORDINATES` and it does not returns all couriers sometimes.

Comment: can you assume that delivery_id is monotonically increasing? if that is the case then you can take the max delivery_id per courier and save yourself some of these correlated subqueries.

Comment: @NickHristov `DELIVERY_ID` is an auto_increment column. But I don't want necessarily the last `DELIVERY_ID`, I need the `DELIVERY_ID` with MAX(`START_DATE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you are only interested in each courier's delivery with the latest start date (if one exists) and each delivery's latest coordinates (if one exists).  So, you should be able to simplify things by limiting those tables before joining.

Ignoring the remaining order count column for now…

```
SELECT c.`COURIER_ID`,
       last_delivery_by_courier.`DELIVERY_ID`,
       last_coordinates_by_delivery.`LAT`,
       last_coordinates_by_delivery.`LNG`
    FROM `COURIERS` AS c
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT d.`COURIER_ID` AS `COURIER_ID`,
                   MAX(d.`DELIVERY_ID`) AS `DELIVERY_ID`
                FROM `DELIVERIES` AS d
                GROUP BY d.`COURIER_ID`
                ORDER BY d.`START_DATE` DESC
                LIMIT 1
        ) AS last_delivery_by_courier
        ON last_delivery_by_courier.`COURIER_ID` = c.`COURIER_ID`
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT coord.`DELIVERY_ID` AS `DELIVERY_ID`,
                   AVG(coord.`LAT`) AS `LAT`,
                   AVG(coord.`LNG`) AS `LNG`
                FROM `COORDINATES` AS coord
                GROUP BY coord.`DELIVERY_ID`
                ORDER BY coord.`DATE` DESC
                LIMIT 1
        ) AS last_coordinates_by_delivery
        ON last_coordinates_by_delivery.`DELIVERY_ID` = last_delivery_by_courier.`DELIVERY_ID`
    ORDER BY last_delivery_by_courier.`START_DATE` DESC
```

Those are uncorrelated subqueries, so you should be able to verify each subquery individually first.

As for the remaining orders… I'm not a fan of subselects in attributes, as they clutter the `SELECT` clause horribly.  Let's try to move the subselect into the `FROM` clause instead.

```
SELECT c.`COURIER_ID`,
       last_delivery_by_courier.`DELIVERY_ID`,
       last_coordinates_by_delivery.`LAT`,
       last_coordinates_by_delivery.`LNG`,
       order_count.`REMAINING_ORDERS`
    FROM `COURIERS` AS c
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT d.`COURIER_ID` AS `COURIER_ID`,
                   MAX(d.`DELIVERY_ID`) AS `DELIVERY_ID`
                FROM `DELIVERIES` AS d
                GROUP BY d.`COURIER_ID`
                ORDER BY d.`START_DATE` DESC
                LIMIT 1
        ) AS last_delivery_by_courier
        ON last_delivery_by_courier.`COURIER_ID` = c.`COURIER_ID`
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT coord.`DELIVERY_ID` AS `DELIVERY_ID`,
                   AVG(coord.`LAT`) AS `LAT`,
                   AVG(coord.`LNG`) AS `LNG`
                FROM `COORDINATES` AS coord
                GROUP BY coord.`DELIVERY_ID`
                ORDER BY coord.`DATE` DESC
                LIMIT 1
        ) AS last_coordinates_by_delivery
        ON last_coordinates_by_delivery.`DELIVERY_ID` = last_delivery_by_courier.`DELIVERY_ID`
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT `ORDERS`.`DELIVERY_ID` AS `DELIVERY_ID`,
                   COUNT(DISTINCT(`ORDER_ID`)) AS `REMAINING_ORDERS`
                FROM `ORDERS`
                WHERE `ORDERS`.`FINISH_DATE` IS NULL
                GROUP BY `ORDERS`.`DELIVERY_ID`
        ) AS order_count
        ON last_delivery_by_courier.`DELIVERY_ID` = order_count.`DELIVERY_ID`
    ORDER BY last_delivery_by_courier.`START_DATE` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your answer and I come back to tell if it worked.

Answer (score 4):

**Distinct**

In a properly designed database, this `DISTINCT` should not be needed:

```
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ORDER_ID`)
   FROM `ORDERS`
```

If multiple different orders can have the same `ORDER_ID`, *we're gonna have a bad time*.

**Aliases**

`c`, `d`, `r`... these are bad table aliases. Why? Because Mr. Maintainer has to go through your entire query to know what those mean, as they are not self-evident. Your table names are pretty short, but if you really need to shorten them further... perhaps something like `crier`, `deliv`, `coord` would be better.

**Join syntax**

This `USING` command:

```
FROM `COURIERS` AS c
LEFT JOIN `DELIVERIES` AS d USING (`COURIER_ID`)
```

`USING` is not standard SQL syntax, when it comes to joins. Sure, it can be a nice shorthand in MySQL, but generally it is preferred to use standard SQL syntax (usually more verbose) instead of depending on syntactic sugar provided by a particular build or version of a language. Like this:

```
FROM `COURIERS` AS c
LEFT JOIN `DELIVERIES` AS d 
ON c.`COURIER_ID` = d.`COURIER_ID`
```

**Performance**

It's a bit difficult to assess performance hiccups if not presented with the execution plan, or a sample dataset to reproduce the issue. If I had to guess, I would say you have too many subqueries in your `CASE` statements.

`CASE` statements are great and very fast when you use constants to compare; but when you use variable values, such as what you are doing... well... it's pretty slow. You're asking the SQL engine to run each subquery for *each record* essentially. It may find a way to optimize that's halfway efficient, but I believe you would be better using a set-based approach. Example:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN
         (SELECT MAX(`START_DATE`)
          FROM `DELIVERIES`
          WHERE `COURIER_ID` = c.`COURIER_ID`) IS NULL THEN d.`START_DATE` IS NULL ELSE -- etc.
```

Instead:

```
-- this goes before your CASE statement
INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DeliveryDates
    SELECT IFNULL( 
        MAX( d.`START_DATE`, NULL ) 
    )
WHERE d.`COURIER_ID` = c.`COURIER_ID`
```

Then:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN
         (SELECT `START_DATE`
            FROM DeliveryDates) IS NULL THEN d.`START_DATE` IS NULL 
        ELSE d.`START_DATE`
```

Answer (score 2):

Before I continue, it appears that your tables are not normalized. Ideally you should normalize them. Anyway, I think this should solve it (though I have not tested it).

```
SELECT C.courier_id, D.delivery_id, O.remaining_orders, COORD.lat, COORD.lng
FROM couriers C
LEFT JOIN (SELECT courier_id, 
                  MAX(start_date) as start_date
                  FROM deliveries
                  GROUP BY courier_id
          ) as D_BY_S ON (C.courier_id = D_BY_S.courier_id)
LEFT JOIN JOIN deliveries D ON (D_BY_S.start_date = D.start_date 
                                AND 
                                D.courier_id = D_BY_S.courier_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT delivery_id, 
                  MAX(date) AS date 
           FROM coordinates
           GROUP BY delivery_id
          ) AS L_COORD ON D.delivery_id = L_COORD.delivery_id
LEFT JOIN coordinates COORD ON (L_COORD.date = COORD.date
                                AND
                                L_COORD.delivery_id = COORD.delivery_id)    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as remaining_orders, 
                  delivery_id 
           FROM orders 
           WHERE finish_date IS NULL
           GROUP BY delivery_id 
          ) AS O ON (O.delivery_id = D.delivery_id)
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your answer and I come back to tell if it worked.